# what does DC Com mean?

Tags: power-supply

I have a international Power Sources Model PUP110-40-S power supply, I think its somewhat generic, that provides +/-12VDC,+/-5VDC.

The unit has failed, and I am attempting to replace it with an ATX PC power supply.

There is a diagram, on the bottom of the Power supply that tells you the voltages on each pin. 2 pins say DC Com. I don't understand what that means.

I can tell you Pin 1, Pin6, which are both labeled DC Com, are not internally wired as common. I'm not sure if I should jumper them together or what.

[image]

Comment: Usually means the DC ground. When you say they're not internally wired as common do you mean they're not connected together? As in you did a connectivity test?

Comment: yes, I mean they are not connected together, I did a continuity test. Thanks for adding the picture! Thats the one!

Comment: Read the datasheet

Comment: @laptop2d The datasheet doesn't define the term "DC COM". But you'd know that if you'd read the datasheet.

Comment: @j0h Are you sure you're testing the right pins? The pinout may be from either the plug side or receptacle side.

Comment: Good point @duskwuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Those are the ground pins.

Even process of elimination leads you there. All have a listed voltage except pin 8 which is N.C. (not connected).

It's feasible that the ±12V and ±5V supplies are generated from separate isolated supplies without the grounds being internally connected. You could check the other side of the connector to see if they're connected on that side.

But, either way, jumpering them together should not be an issue. I base that on the fact that they didn't label them as separate nets.

Comment: The DC COM is usually what we'd call 'ground', but it isn't called ground on the label because that would require a fire-safety test of the AC power protection that would put an extraordinary amount of current (30A, typically) through the wires.

Comment: @Whit3rd Interesting, so you suggest they're specifically not calling it ground to avoid regulatory testing? Is that for UL or some  other regulatory agency?

Comment: yes, in testing against most fault-protection-ground for AC circuitry, ground wiring (that might be used to bond a metal case, for instance) is subject to all kinds of extra scrutiny.  The power supply making current limited low voltage does not need that level of testing, but might get it if the labeling isn't clear.

Answer (score 0):

"Com" is an abbreviation for "common" -- those pins are the neutral/ground connection.

Note that you may have some difficulty finding a PC power supply that can provide 1A at -5V and -12V. Most newer power supplies do not provide -5V at all, as it was removed from the ATX standard in 2003.